# Grails GORM criteria on null association

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain object with an associated domain object which I'd like to be able to search on as part of a query.

Using the Book model as an example, I'd have:

```
public class Book{
    Author author
    String title
}

public class Author{
    String name
}
```

.. and want to filter like:

```
def book = Book.withCriteria{
    or{
        ilike(title, "%" + params.filter + "%")
        author{
            ilike("name", "%" + params.filter + "%")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that if I include author in the query, then any "Books" with a null author will not be returned, even if the title matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's likely due to the implicit inner join being created between Book and Author. Try using a left outer join like this:

```
def book = Book.withCriteria{
    createAlias 'author', 'auth', org.hibernate.sql.JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN
    or{
        ilike(title, "%" + params.filter + "%")
        ilike("auth.name", "%" + params.filter + "%")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is probably what I need, but I'm getting a strange error saying "No such property: hibernate for class: ..." for one of my domain classes included in the query

Comment: What's the entire exception message?

Comment: "No such property: hibernate for class: com.mypackage.MyDomainObject"

Comment: It looks like your missing the "org". It should be  org.hibernate.sql.JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN

Comment: ohhhhhhhh, I feel stupid, we have a local variable named "org", so it wasn't resolving it as the full qualified name but as a property on that variable

Comment: It couldn't find org.hibernate.sql.JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, but org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN worked. Thanks for your help