# How to left join with 2 table with a condition in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0, hibernate-criteria

Using Grails 2.1.1, I need to build a query with 2 tables using left join. If I query it in Oracle, it's working and giving me the correct result. When I'm using grails controller, I get an error.

Here are my attempts below:

My query which works on Oracle:

```
SELECT  MS.* FROM 
   SLS_DO_MST MS  LEFT OUTER JOIN INV_ISSUE ISS 
   ON MS.MID = ISS.SLS_DO_MST_MID 
   where ISS.SLS_DO_MST_MID is null
```

My hql query which I'm using in the grails controller:

```
def items = SlsDoMst.executeQuery('select a from sls.dlo.SlsDoMst a left outer join  inv.InvIssue b on a.id = b.slsDoMst.id where b.slsDoMst.id is null')
```

The error I get:

```
unexpected token: on near line 1, column 66 [select a from sls.dlo.SlsDoMst a left outer join  inv.InvIssue b on a.id = b.slsDoMst.id where b.slsDoMst.id is null]
```

**My domain as follows.**

My SlsDoMst domain:

```
    class SlsDoMst {

    ...

    static mapping = {
        ...
    }

    static constraints = {
        ...
    }
}
```

My InvIssue domain:

```
    class InvIssue{
    static mapping = {
        table 'INV_ISSUE'
        slsDoMst column: 'SLS_DO_MST_MID',ignoreNotFound: true
        ...
    }

    ...
    SlsDoMst slsDoMst

    static constraints = {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `on` for a left join in HQL. Hibernate decides which column be used for the join clause by **model definition**.

You need to define a relation(e.g. `hasMany`) and `mapping` on models used by join on HQL.

Here is the reference:
https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.3/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html

Comment: any source code example for my purpose will be great

Comment: @SumonBappi I need a model definition that you wrote because there are some different ways.

Comment: Here's an example of a left outer join as a criteria query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751113/grails-gorm-criteria-on-null-association/32751847#32751847 And here are examples of all the join types in HQL, criteria, and where queries: http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-from-clause/

Comment: @sndyuk I have added my domain. Can you please help